# Searching through the protocol buffer file

Tags: protocol-buffers

I'm new to protocol buffers and I was wondering whether it was possible to search a protocol buffers binary file and read the data in a structured format. For example if a message in my .proto file has 4 fields I would like to serialize the message and write multiple messages into a file and then search for a particular field in the file. If I find the field I would like to read back the message in the same structured format as it was written. Is this possible with protocol buffers ? If possible any sample code or examples would be very helpful. Thank you

Comment: What platform / client library are you using? There are many. The answer depends on which.

Comment: I plan on using the c++ protobuf complier and the c++ protobuf APIs

Answer (score 0):

You should treat protobuf library as one serialization protocol, not an all-in-one library which supports complex operations (such as querying, indexing, picking up particular data). Google has various libraries on top of open-sourced portion of protobuf to do so, but they are not released as open source, as they are tied with their unique infrastructure. That being said, what you want is certainly possible, yet you need to write some code.

Anyhow, some of your requirements are:

1. one file contains various serialized binaries.
2. search a particular field in each serialized binary and extract that chunk.

There are several ways to achieve them.

1. The most popular way for serial read/write is that the file contains a series of [size, type, serialization output]. That is, one serialized output is always prefixed by size and type (either 4/8 byte or variable-length) to help reading and parsing. So you just repeat this procedure: 1) read size and type, 2) read binary with given size, 3) parse with given type 4) goto 1). If you use union type or one file shares same type, you may skip type. You cannot drop size, as there is no way know the end of output by itself. If you want random read/write, other type of data structure is necessary.
2. 'search field' in binary file is more tricky. One way is to read/parse output one by one and to check the existance of field by HasField(). It is most obvious and slow yet straightforward way to do so. If you want to search field by number (say, you want to search 'optional string email = 3;'), thus search by binary blob (like 0x1A, field number 3, wire type 2), it is not possible. In a serialized binary stream, field information is saved merely a number. Without an exact context (.proto scheme or binary file's structure), the number alone doesn't mean anything. There is no guarantee that 0x1A is from field information, or field information from other message type, or actually number 26, or part of other number, etc. That is, you need to maintain the information by yourself. You may create another file or database with necessary information to fetch particular message (like the location of serialization output with given field).

Long story short, what you ask is beyond what open-sourced protobuf library itself does, yet you can write them with your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I hope, this is what you are looking for: 
http://temk.github.io/protobuf-utils/

This is a command line utility for searching within protobuf file.